# Regex Repeatead Consecutive Characters IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I'm trying to valide an iOS textfield with a regex for **no** repeated consecutive characteres

eg. txt12344 -> should fail

this is my code

```
NSString *regexConsecutive = @"(.)\1{1,}";
NSPredicate *passConsecutivePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regexConsecutive];

if ([passConsecutivePredicate evaluateWithObject:self.txtPassword.text]){
    errorMessage = @"No repeated consecutive characters allowed !";
}
```

but I'm not sure if self matches it's the right way to achieve this.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html

Comment: I don't think you'll need the `{1,}` on the end.

Comment: Ok you're right, i've been finding around the web, but my match is still not working, i would really appreciate your help